VSCode snippet to place selected text in the middle of fixed-length comment block
Using VSCode snippets, I would like to have the following behaviour. Say I select the word "foobarbaz", then (using a snippet) I would like it to turn into
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                  foobarbaz                                 */
/******************************************************************************/

where the length of the comment block is fixed. This means that the number of spaces before and after "foobarbaz" depends on the length of "foobarbaz" itself. The idea is that the number of spaces on the left and on the right of the selected word is the same. In the cases where the length of the word is an odd number, I would have the left number of spaces to be one less than the right number of spaces.
Would it be possible to have this behviour implemented with VSCode snippets, or is it too complex?

have a look at the Hypersnips extension

there is an extension in vscode called Comment Bars that does the trick. with your arbitrary filler character.


Using an extension I wrote, Comment Blocks, this is quite easy.
Either this setting (in your settings.json):
"commentBlocks.defaults": {  
  "subjects": ["", "${selectedText}", ""],    
  "padLines": ["*", " ", "*"]
}

and a keybinding to trigger it (in your keybindings.json):
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "comment-blocks.createBlock"
}

Or just a keybinding:
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "comment-blocks.createBlock",
  "args": {
    "subjects": ["", "${selectedText}", ""],    // three lines to the block
    "padLines": ["*", " ", "*"]    // pad each line separately, middle line with spaces
  }
}

will do this:


The extension can do a lot more customization, it just happens that your example is pretty simple and uses some of the defaults set by the extension, like "justify": "center".
Options are:
  selectCurrentLine?: boolean,         // default is true
  lineLength: number | Array<number>,  // default is 80
  startText: string | Array<string>,   // default to block comment start
  endText: string | Array<string>,     // default to block comment end
  justify: string | Array<string>,     // default is center (left/right)
  gapLeft: number | Array<number>,     // spaces around the text
  gapRight: number | Array<number>,    
  padLines: string | Array<string>,    // what character to pad out each line
  subjects: Array<string>              // like ${selectedText}

